# Flux V2 ImagePolicy version list argument cannot be empty

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, fluxcd

I have the following imagepolicy:

```
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1alpha2
kind: ImagePolicy
metadata:
  name: cps-kul-beta-imagepolicy
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  imageRepositoryRef:
    name: cps-kul-image
  filterTags:
    pattern: '^sha-(?P<ts>.*)-.+'
    extract: '$ts'
  policy:
    numerical:
      order: asc
```

And I get the error `version list argument cannot be empty` when doing kubectl describe on that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that there's no images in the registry which conform to the tag pattern prescribed in the filterTags section. Uploading a new image to the registry will fix this problem.

Comment: Nice, I added it to `exclusionList` in `Alert` spec.

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I'm not sure that missing images are the only source of this error, I'm just a regular user. What's the effect of adding it to the exclusionlist by the way?

Comment: Since the error message is not reflective of "no images in registry" its not a useful alert hence adding it to `exclustionList` will prevent Flux to fire an Alert - so in my case I don't get a Slack notification because even if I did its not helpful.